# Empty string in Delphi / Windows combo box causes access exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I've got a Delphi 7.0 application that throws a memory access exception / message box every time it writeln's an empty string from the string list associated with a combo box:

```
csvstrlst := combobox1.Items;

csvstrlst.clear;
csvstrlst.add('');    //problem
csvstrlst.add('a');   //no problem
csvstrlst.add('');    //problem
csvstrlst.add('b');   //no problem

//throws memory access messages (I think the writeln writes a line though)
for n := 1 to csvstrlst.Count do begin
    writeln(out_file,csvstrlst.strings[n-1])
end;

//throws memory access messages (writeln does write a comma text string though)
writeln(out_file,csvstrlst.commatext);
```

Running on Windows 7 or XP. As application or in D7 IDE. Combobox with empty string items also causes the same error if the parent of the form it is on is changed.

Has anyone else ever seen or heard of this problem? Any other information available at all?

Comment: did you tried compiling the program with VCL FixPack ?

Comment: I'm bemused that the question tags have been removed. The error causes an access-violation: the [access-violation] tag has been removed. The items property and the strlst variable are both Tstringlist: the [Tstringlist] tag has been removed. The items property comes from a combobox on a form: the [combobox] tag has been removed. The access violation only happens with an empty string: the [empty-string] tag was removed THESE WERE THE TAGS i SEARCHED FOR TO FIND A SOLUTION, BECAUSE THIS WAS THE DESCRIPTION OF THE PROBLEM. What's the point here? Why hide the question?

Comment: "The items property and the strlst variable are both Tstringlist" No they are not. And you've been told that below SR's answer explicitly. http://lazarus-ccr.sourceforge.net/docs/lcl/stdctrls/tcustomcombobox.items.html http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TCustomCombo.Items Also that freed the room to [tag:delphi-7] tag, and the bug IS local to preliminary non-upgraded Delphi 7. So i exchanged the incorrect tag for the correct one.

Comment: So you will be editing back [access-violation] and [combobox]?

Comment: I did not changed those. I explained my change. Ask the person wjo did THAT change. And use `@name` convention to address people - otherwise they would not even know you spoke to them. Look as it is done in other places on StackOverflow

Comment: BTW, @david, did you looked at the history of editions of your question before asking ?

Comment: I removed those tags because they don't add any value. Only a tiny proportion of questions relating to AVs or combo boxes will have those tags. So searching within those tags will not help you. If you really want to search on this site, you need to use an external search index. For example search on Google using site:stackoverflow.com Tagging is only effective if questions are reliably and accurately tagged. For mainstream tags, e.g. language tags, that happens. For off-the-beaten track tags like the ones you used, not so much. They serve no real purpose.

Comment: @Arioch'The Looks like our edits crossed. Sorry.

Comment: @david How did you resolve the actual problem?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "For off-the-beaten track tags" Doesn't this becoming hen and egg problem (or perhaps self-fulfilled prophecy)? you removed tags where they seem being relevant at least to some extent,that is, you decreased "useful signal level" - and then you are sad that SNR is bad on the tags' "channels". Perhaps the question may be put "what was wrong with those tags? what harm did they brought?" "TStringList" tag was both incorrect and occupying the slot i needed for more relevant tag. But for those tags...  they maybe redundant, but i fail to see the harm from them being put here.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "our edits crossed" not at all, you clearly inherited my "delphi-7" tag... Ah! i see! no, i was addressing "david" the topic starter not "David Heffernan" the editor :-D

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, resolved by removing empty lines from the string list property of the combobox, where they were causing related problems as well as the specific question asked here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known and solved bug described in QC:

[TCombobox gives AV when selecting empty item from dropdown](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2246)

---

Although this is a bug, you should not reuse parts from controls to perform some data tasks as described in your question.

You will not save anything doing so, but getting most the time unwanted sideeffects (controls get repainted and/or fire events)

If you want to have a `TStringList` then create an instance.

```
csvstrlst := TStringList.Create;
try

  // csvstrlst.Clear;
  csvstrlst.Add( '' );
  csvstrlst.Add( 'a' );
  csvstrlst.Add( '' );
  csvstrlst.Add( 'b' );

  for n := 0 to csvstrlst.Count - 1 do 
  begin
    WriteLn( out_file, csvstrlst[n] )
  end;

  WriteLn( out_file, csvstrlst.CommaText );

finally
  csvstrlst.Free;
end;
```

Comment: The QC report is the key here. `Items` is a `TStrings` and should not throw AVs. You should not have to use a `TStringList`. It's a bug in the VCL.

Comment: In fact looking at the edit history, I can see that you added the QC link after the initial version of the answer. Frankly the first part of the answer, everything before the QC report link is spurious. It's just a bug. All you should have in the answer is the QC link. Discussions about `TStringList` are pointless because the question is not about `TStringList`, it's about `TComboBox`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll edit my answer an put the QC link on top

Comment: "Although this is a bug, you should not reuse parts from controls to perform some data tasks as described in your question." What makes you think that the question asker is doing that? I imagined that the asker has simply cut the problem down a bit to present it to us. This statement supports that: *Combobox with empty string items also causes the same error if the parent of the form it is on is changed.*

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To me it is not a *simple* cut down of the problem. Simple would have been 3 lines of code `combobox1.Items.Clear; combobox1.Items.Add(''); combobox1.Items[0];`. But you are right it is just a guess from me, that the code shows something from real code, but it smells like :o)

Answer (score 2):

As Sir Rufo has discovered the issue is a VCL bug introduced in Delphi 7 as described in [QC#2246](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=2246). According to that report the bug is resolved in a build with major version number 7 so you may be able to fix the problem by applying the latest Delphi 7 updates.

If not then you can fix the problem from the outside. I don't actually have a Delphi 7 installation to test this on, but I believe that this interposer class will work.

```
type
  TFixedComboBoxStrings = class(TComboBoxStrings)
  protected
    function Get(Index: Integer): string; override;
  end;

  TComboBox = class(StdCtrls.TComboBox)
  protected
    function GetItemsClass: TCustomComboBoxStringsClass; override;
  end;

function TFixedComboBoxStrings.Get(Index: Integer): string;
var
  Len: Integer;
begin
  Len := SendMessage(ComboBox.Handle, CB_GETLBTEXTLEN, Index, 0);
  if (Len <> CB_ERR) and (Len > 0) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, Len);
    SendMessage(ComboBox.Handle, CB_GETLBTEXT, Index, Longint(PChar(Result)));
  end
  else
    SetLength(Result, 0);
end;

function TComboBox.GetItemsClass: TCustomComboBoxStringsClass;
begin
  Result := TFixedComboBoxStrings;
end;
```

---

The bug that was introduced in Delphi 7 is simply that the `if` statement reads:

```
if Len <> CB_ERR then
```

So, when `Len` is zero, that is when the item is the empty string, the `True` branch of the `if` is chosen. Then, the `SendMessage` becomes:

```
SendMessage(ComboBox.Handle, CB_GETLBTEXT, Index, Longint(PChar('')));
```

Now, `PChar('')` has special treatment and evaluates to a pointer to read only memory containing a zero character. And so when the combo box window procedure attempts to write to that memory, an access violation occurs because the memory is read only.